# Android: App crashes while entering invalid location

Tags: android, location

In my app, I have to find whether a given location comes under a specified area. I am taking Connaught Place, New Delhi as center point. and I got the addresses which come under area of 200 miles from center point. But, if I enter any invalid location, like "abcdfdfkc", the app crashes, because it is trying to find coordinates of this location and I want to avoid this.

Below I am posting the code:

```
public static  boolean isServicedLocation(Context _ctx, String strAddress){
    boolean isServicedLocation = false;

    Address sourceAddress = getAddress(_ctx, "Connaught Place, New Delhi, India");
    Location sourceLocation = new Location("");
    sourceLocation.setLatitude(sourceAddress.getLatitude());
    sourceLocation.setLongitude(sourceAddress.getLongitude());      

    Address targetAddress = getAddress(_ctx, strAddress);
    Location targetLocation = new Location("");

    if (targetLocation != null) {
        targetLocation.setLatitude(targetAddress.getLatitude());
        targetLocation.setLongitude(targetAddress.getLongitude());
        float distance = Math.abs(sourceLocation.distanceTo(targetLocation));
        double distanceMiles = distance/1609.34;
        isServicedLocation = distanceMiles <= 200;

        //Toast.makeText(_ctx, "Distance "+distanceMiles, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }       

    return isServicedLocation;
}
```

**getAddress method:**

```
public static Address getAddress(Context _ctx, String addressStr) {
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(_ctx, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(addressStr,
                1);

        if (addresses.size() != 0) {
            return addresses.get(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you don't find an address from the GeoCoder (ie, if `addresses.size() == 0`), you return `null`.

Then, regardless of that, you dereference the value, which is what's crashing your app.

```
Address targetAddress = getAddress(_ctx, strAddress);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
:
if (targetLocation != null) {
    targetLocation.setLatitude(targetAddress.getLatitude());
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should probably also be checking `targetAddress` for `null` to avoid this (either in addition to (likely), or instead of (less likely), the check of `targetLocation`).

So I'd be looking at changing:

```
if (targetLocation != null) {
```

into:

```
if ((targetLocation != null) && (targetAddress != null)) {
```

That way, an invalid address automatically becomes an unserviced location.